# android layout filename is green? and everything else is red

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hybC5.png

Can anyone explain why the text for one of my files is green?

The code for my layouts is working, and it usually would be underlined with red if there was a problem.

Any changes that I have made in the green file are also not showing up, in my specific case, a button is added to the green file but it's not being displayed

Comment: As far as I know, it should be related to version control.

Answer (score 12):

This color coding has nothing to do with errors. *Green* indicates new files in the version control system (e.g., git), *red* is for files that are not added to the VCS, *blue* - for changed files since last commit, and *white* - for ignored files.

Comment: can you tell me how to use GIT with Android studio projects

Comment: @PankajNimgade I'm afraid I will need to point you to the official docs, because it's just impossible to discuss all the peculiarities involved in this process within the scope of the original question [1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control.html), [2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control-with-intellij-idea.html), and [3](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/git.html).